# Wacom Draw Tablet Not Detected By System Settings

Tags: wacom

My tablet is plugged in and working well, however, when I go to the System Settings, it says that no tablet is detected.

Everything else is working fine except for this, which makes it very frustrating as I can not configure the buttons and Express Keys.

Thanks

Comment: This can be a problem on many versions of Ubuntu, as the Wacom control panel is a GNOME feature loosely ported to Unity. You should list your Ubuntu version 'lsb_release -a' and your kernel version 'uname -a' as well as your Wacom device 'lsusb' will give the VID/PID for the device.

Comment: You may want to have a look at http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Tablet_Configuration and http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Xsetwacom which will let you configure the buttons and the ExpressKeys from the commandline.